# finding a record with maximal value in SAS

Tags: sas

How do I find a record of maximal value in SAS? I have a dataset of the following structure:

```
age name
12 joe
15 jane
3  bob
14 rick
```

I would like to find the value of 'name' for which 'age' is the maximal (in this example - 'jane').

I tried this:

```
 data max;
   set ages_data;
   if age > max_age then do;
       max_age = age;
   max_name = name;
   end;
   retain max_:;
   keep max_:;
 run;
```

which is based on what I found here:
https://communities.sas.com/message/170554

but it didn't work for me... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine - but is outputting all records, I assume you expected just one?  Try the following changes:

```
 data max;
   set ages_data end=lastobs; /* identify last record */
   if age > max_age then do;
      max_age = age;
      max_name = name;
   end;
   retain max_:;
   keep max_:;
   if lastobs then output; /* only output last record */
 run;
```

One drawback with this approach is that it will only output the FIRST value of name, for a given maximum age.  There may be multiple values of name for that age.  The following approach may be more robust for your purposes:

```
 proc sql;
 create table max as
    select name, age
    from ages_data
    where age= (select max(age) from ages_data);
```

In case it's useful - here are the datalines for testing:

```
data ages_data;
infile cards;
input age name $;
cards;
12 joe
15 jane
3  bob
14 rick
;run;
```